# Исторические морфемы в слове "несуразный"

Tags: этимология, лексика

У Даля есть статья о слове "несуразный", там указано несколько значений,  но значение самой корневой основы и  происхождение слова неясно.

https://slovar.cc/rus/dal/577358.html

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, на который Вы хотели бы получить ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Историческое членение на морфемы: не-су-раз-н-ый.

*Несуразный* происходит от *суразный* (суразица 'сраженное, сброшенное и потому лежащее вместе с другим'); последнее, в свою очередь, восходит к сочетанию префикса су- и корня *раз* — того же, что и в глаголах *разить*, *резать*.

См. «Историю слов» В. В. Виноградова, «Этимологический словарь русского языка» М. Фасмера.

Answer (score -1):

Раз, разный, развитие, разъединение. Суть целое на части, что значит развитие природы. В русской азбуке звук "у" и "о" взаимозаменяемы, в азбуке не было буквы у была оук, значит суразный вполне заменятся на  соразный, (аналогично соразмерный) т.е. разнообразный - в гармонии с природой. Таким образом, несуразный значит не в гармонии.

Comment: Увы, вы допускаете как минимум две большие ошибки: а) в «русской азбуке» нет взаимозаменяемых звуков; б) то, что вы называете оуком, читалось как [ук] — [о] никогда не произносился. Эта буква представляет собой диграф, соответствуя при этом одной фонеме.